# Google Cloud Storage require is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I writing a React web app and want to save users' files to GCP.
First of all, I get files at my backend server (express), I check size and MIME type, then I want to save those files to GCP.
I read docs and make the same in my code.
But I've got an Error 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'
Did anybody have experience with that problem?

```
node -v 13.13.0
npm  -v 6.14.4
express -v 4.17.1
```

Error message:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node server.js`
node     | (node:84) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
node     | file:///usr/src/meow/routes/master.js:11
node     | const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
node     |                     ^
node     |
node     | ReferenceError: require is not defined
node     |     at file:///usr/src/meow/routes/master.js:11:21
node     |     at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:110:37)
node     |     at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
node     | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My Code

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage(
    { keyFilename: "../config/GCP_key.json" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue!
The promlem was using ECMAScript Modules.
I refactor code:
Change all 'import XXX from "XXX" on const XXX = require(XXX)
Remove type:"module" in package.json
Remove "--experimental-modules" in nodemon statup command